Order by author name when a book may have more than one author
I've got a book catalogue db. Each book can have one or more authors. Example:
book #1 by John Red
book #2 by Fred Green and Steve Blue
book #3 by Ben Brown
ARTICLES table:



id
title




1
Book1


2
Book2


3
Book3



AUTHORS table:



id
surname
name




1
Red
John


2
Green
Fred


3
Blue
Steve


4
Brown
Ben



AUTHORS_ARTICLES table:



id_author
id_article




1
1


2
2


3
2


4
3



I need to retrieve books' details, sorted in alphabetical order by author.
I am using the following query:
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM articles a
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors_articles aa ON a.id = aa.id_article
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors au ON aa.id_author = au.id
ORDER BY au.surname ASC, au.name ASC

The problem is that books do not always get sorted alphabetically by authors' surname/name: when there are two or more authors for a book, the first author appearing in the link table (authors_articles) will be the one returned from the query, and that is not necessarily the first in alphabetical order. Still, it will be used by the ORDER BY clause at the end of query, resulting in erroneous order of records.
The result for my current query is:



id
title




3
Book3


2
Book2


1
Book1



Notice that the book by Brown comes first, even when Book2 is authored by Green AND Blue.
I would need them to be listed as Book2, Book3 and Book1, instead.
Any help will be appreciated.

You need to find the first author per book before you can perform an order by. A simple row_number query could be used for that:
with cte as (
  select
    articles.*,
    authors.surname,
    authors.name,
    row_number() over (
      partition by articles.id
      order by authors.surname, authors.name
    ) as rn
  from articles
  left join authors_articles on articles.id =  authors_articles.id_article
  left join authors on authors_articles.id_author = authors.id
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
order by surname, name


Hmm, actually, there's an issue: a book can be associated to other properties, like languages for instance. The solution by Salman A works only if there's one language associated to the book, while if there're more then the select does not return any result.

That changes the question entirely and I am not editig my answer.

Since you had taken the liberty to edit my question, I thought you might also edit your answer... never mind, thanks for your help anyway.
